# How to make a node red?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-graph,tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = stealth, % arrow head style
        shorten > = 1pt, % don't touch arrow head to node
        auto,
        node distance = 3cm, % distance between nodes
        semithick % line style
    ]

\tikzstyle{every state}=[
        draw = black,
        thick,
        fill = white,
        minimum size = 4mm
    ]

    \node[state] (5)  {5};
    \node[state] (2) [right of=5] {2};
    \node[state] (4) [below left of=2] {4};
    \node[state] (3) [below right of=4] {3};
    \node[state] (6) [left of=3] {6};
    \node[state] (1) [above right of=3] {1};

    \path[->] (2) edge node {5} (5);
    \path[->] (5) edge node {15} (4);
    \path[->] (6) edge node {10} (5);
    \path[->] (6) edge node {4} (4);
    \path[->] (2) edge node {30} (6);
    \path[->] (3) edge node {15} (6);
    \path[->] (3) edge node {4} (2);
    \path[->] (2) edge node {20} (1.west);
    \path[->] (1) edge node {2} (2.east);
    \path[->] (1) edge node {15} (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I only want one node which is 5 to be red, how to do it?

[image]

Comment: `\node[state, red] (5)  {5};` ?

Comment: @cfr It only changes the color of "5", but I think it has reached my purpose.

Comment: `\node[state, red, draw=red]` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you can use the code

```
\tikzstyle{red state}=[
        draw = red,
        thick,
        fill = white,
        minimum size = 4mm,
        circle
    ]

    \node[red state] (5)  {5};
```

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-graph,tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, automata}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        > = stealth, % arrow head style
        shorten > = 1pt, % don't touch arrow head to node
        auto,
        node distance = 3cm, % distance between nodes
        semithick % line style
    ]

\tikzstyle{every state}=[
        draw = black,
        thick,
        fill = white,
        minimum size = 4mm
    ]

\tikzstyle{red state}=[
        draw = red,
        thick,
        fill = white,
        minimum size = 4mm,
        circle
    ]

    \node[red state] (5)  {5};
    \node[state] (2) [right of=5] {2};
    \node[state] (4) [below left of=2] {4};
    \node[state] (3) [below right of=4] {3};
    \node[state] (6) [left of=3] {6};
    \node[state] (1) [above right of=3] {1};

    \path[->] (2) edge node {5} (5);
    \path[->] (5) edge node {15} (4);
    \path[->] (6) edge node {10} (5);
    \path[->] (6) edge node {4} (4);
    \path[->] (2) edge node {30} (6);
    \path[->] (3) edge node {15} (6);
    \path[->] (3) edge node {4} (2);
    \path[->] (2) edge node {20} (1.west);
    \path[->] (1) edge node {2} (2.east);
    \path[->] (1) edge node {15} (3);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add to a style,

- inline: `\node[state, draw = red] (5)  {5};`
- or in a definition: `\tikzstyle{red state} = [ state, draw = red ]`

If you define every style from scratch, such as the other solution

```
\tikzstyle{red state} = [
        draw = red,
        thick,
        fill = white,
        minimum size = 4mm,
        circle
    ]
```

then you have to adjust all such styles if you would change the base style.

I rather define

- a base node style
- a colored version of the base node style via `[base, draw = ...]`
- another emphasized version of the base node style such as via `[base, fill = ...]`
- ...

so I can easily change the base node style and all derived styles inherit the change immediately.